# Store list contents as two different lists with same indices

Tags: python, arrays, list

so I'm trying to store a list of contents within two different matrices depending on where I'm reading the code from. In other words, I'm going to be reading in a list with this pattern:

```
['1', '1', '-1'], ['1', '1', '-1'], ['1', '1', '-1'], [], ['1', '1', '-1'], [], 
['1', '2', '-1'], ['1', '2', '-1'], ['1', '2', '-1'], [], ['1', '2', '-1'], [], etc
```

and what I want to do is read and store everything before the first space in a 2D array such as:

```
inputs[i] = ['1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1']
inputs[i+1] = ['1', '2', '-1', '1', '2', '-1', '1', '2', '-1']
```

Then the next set of numbers after the space as:

```
outputs[i] = ['1', '1', '-1']
outputs[i+1] = ['1', '2', '-1']
```

While repeating with an increment of i+1 after I've stored the corresponding outputs.

I don't necessarily want to hard code everything because the number of inputs could be different (ie I could have 4 lists of inputs before you get to the space before the outputs). I've tried doing a for loop like:

```
l = ['1', '1', '-1'], ['1', '1', '-1'], ['1', '1', '-1'], [], ['1', '1', '-1'], [], 
['1', '1', '-1'], ['1', '1', '-1'], ['1', '1', '-1'], [], ['1', '1', '-1'], [], etc

for line in l:
    if line != []:
        inputs[i].append(line) 
    else:
        outputs[i].append(line.next) # Get that output line
        line.next() # To skip the following blank line
```

The problem I have is that I'm not sure where to increment i, and that depending on where i gets incremented, the outputs and inputs won't be on the same index. What would be the best way to store something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, the list you want to process contains this kind of sequence:

> ```
> inputs empty output empty inputs empty output empty inputs empty output empty inputs empty output empty ...
> ```

That is, multiple sets of inputs and outputs, delimited by empty lists.

As you iterate over the items in the incoming list.
You could use a flag variable to track whether you're in the middle of processing inputs or outputs, for example like this:

```
inputs = [[]]
outputs = []
input_mode = True

for lst in lists:
    if not lst:
        if not input_mode:
            inputs.append([])
        # flip the mode
        input_mode = not input_mode
    elif input_mode:
        # extend last input list
        inputs[-1].extend(lst)
    else:
        outputs.append(lst)
```

For example given:

```
lists = ['1', '1', '-1'], ['1', '1', '-1'], ['1', '1', '-3'], [], ['1', '1', '-4'], [], ['1', '1', '-1'], ['1', '1', '-1'], ['1', '1', '-7'], [], ['1', '1', '-8']
```

The above implementation will produce `inputs` and `outputs` as:

```
[['1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '-3'], ['1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '1', '1', '-7']]
[['1', '1', '-4'], ['1', '1', '-8']]
```

Comment: Yes, that's close, but I think you have the inputs and outputs switched as your code displays my desired outputs under the inputs variable. However, I think my description of the desired inputs might not be clear so I'll edit it.

Comment: @BrxttB I don't see why it doesn't match what you described. I added a concrete example, please clarify what is different from what you intended.

Comment: When I run the program, I get inputs:      [['1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1'], ['-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1'] , etc # Which should be the outputs. Outputs = : [['-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1'], ['-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1'], ['-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1'], ['-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1'], etc, but they should be the inputs, and I would want it to be of the form: inputs[0] = [['-1', '-1', '1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '1', '-1', '1', '-1', '-1'].

Comment: So basically inputs[0] = all of the inputs before the space, outputs[0] . unless The inputs/outputs are backwards which I can try, but my output is different from yours. , where yours is my desired output.

Comment: @BrxttB For the example input that I wrote, if you don't get the example output that I wrote, then you must have made a mistake somewhere when copying the code.

Comment: I think the problem was that there was an empty list at the beginning which might have affected my output versus your output. However it works, thank you for bearing with me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about you want to do.
First of all, if the variable i depends content of lines (you don't predict where is incremented), best way may be do a list:

```
input = []
output = []
```

And if you want to store a new value in them use append function:

```
input.append(aux)
```

on aux:

```
isInput = True
aux = []
for line in l:
    if line != []:
        if isInput:
            inputs.append([aux]) 
            isInput = False
        else:
            outputs.append([aux])
            isInput = True
        aux = []
    else:
        aux.append(line.next) # Get that output line
        line.next() # To skip the following blank line
```